# How can I default to IE for testing my ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Three fine browsers I have installed: the inimitable Mozilla, the traditional Internet Explorer, and the hot new Chrome. I love them all dearly, but when testing my ASP.NET application, I would prefer to do so using IE.

Please note, I've not *deployed* this application. I'm merely launching it from the Visual Studio project in which it was conceived. Would someone here be so good as to suggest a way in which I might specify the browser it launches in? Thank you.

Comment: @Shog9: is it possible to +1 an edit?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click on any `.aspx` page in Solution Explorer and choose **Browse With...**

You can then select *Internet Explorer* from the list and choose '**Set as Default**' to make pages open with IE when you press `F5`.

Comment: i mean when I hit F5 key to start application it shd open in IE and not Chrome

Comment: @deepti: Yes, that will do it. I've updated my answer to reflect exactly that.

Comment: when i right click on my aspx page inside project .. i cant find any option browse with..

Comment: @deepti: Are you sure? This has been in VS since at least 2005... you're clicking in Solution Explorer, right?

Comment: @deepti: Good stuff. It's generally accepted practice to accept the earliest correct answer rather than the latest.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click and ASPX file in your solution explorer
2. Go > File > Browse with.. > Select IE then set it as your defautl browser.
3. Run your project.

Comment: Go > File > Browse -- can you describe this

Comment: Click the File menu at the top of Visual Studio window then look for "Browse With" (make sure you have a .ASPX page selected otherwise it will not display the Browse With option. If you cant see the Solution Explorer hit (Ctrl+Alt+L)