# how i can change default browser when running .net projects

Tags: asp.net

net project then it runs in mozilla. I want to change that setting & i want in internet explorer, how i can do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of: [How can I default to IE for testing my ASP.NET application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638177/how-can-i-default-to-ie-for-testing-my-asp-net-application/5638193#5638193)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `File` menu, select `Browse with...`, and choose your default browser.

Be sure to have a web site project loaded and selected otherwise the option won't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Just Right-Click on a folder or a `.aspx` file in your project and Choose "`Browse with...`" from there. Then set your desired browser as default via the "`Set as Default`" button and click browse. That's it.

Next time you start debugging the site will open in your default browser.